# Change visible text onscroll and prevent page scroll for this time

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transform, onscroll

enter code hereI want to add a section to my page where a process should be visualized with text blocks for every process step. For example the process has 9 steps and I want that only 3 steps are visible at the same time. So starting with steps 1, 2 and 3 I want that the next steps are visible onscroll. It should be like a animation where the visible steps are all the time at the same position. So I want to rotate the steps from visible to unvisible and reverse on scroll. Untill the last step is visible I want to prevent the scroll behaviour from its normal behaviour to scroll the page to the next section.

It should look like this:[image]

```js
let processSteps = [
    {
      "position":"1",
      "title":"1. Analyzing",
      "info": "In this step we will perform an analyzis"
    },
    {
      "position":"2",
      "title":"2. Goal definition",
      "info": "In this step we will perform an analyzis"
    },
    {
      "position":"3",
      "title":"3. Designing",
      "info": "In this step we will perform an analyzis"
    },
    {
      "position":"4",
      "title":"4. Development",
      "info": "In this step we will perform an analyzis"
    },
    {
      "position":"5",
      "title":"5. Production",
      "info": "In this step we will perform an analyzis"
    },
    {
      "position":"6",
      "title":"6. Optimization",
      "info": "In this step we will perform an analyzis"
    }
  ];
  
let lastVisibleProcessStep = 3;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    stickElement("#section-two", "fixed");
});

function stickElement(object, name) {
    if (IsVisible(object)) {
        $(object).addClass(name);
        scrollProcess();
    } else {
        $(object).removeClass(name);
    }
}

function IsVisible(object) {
    var viewport = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var rand = $(object).offset();
    rand.bottom = rand.top + $(object).outerHeight();
    return !(
        viewport < rand.top + 250 || $(window).scrollTop() > rand.bottom - 250
    );
}

function scrollProcess() {
  if ( lastVisibleProcessStep < processSteps.length ) {
    $(".process-steps:first-child h5").html(processSteps[lastVisibleProcessStep - 2].title);
    lastVisibleProcessStep++;
  }
}
```

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#section-one {
  background-color: green;
}
#section-two {
  background-color: grey;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#section-three {
  background-color: black;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.process-step-headline {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.process-step-info {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section" id="section-one"></section>
<section class="section" id="section-two">
  <div class="process-steps" process-step="1">
    <h5 class="process-step-headline">1. Analyzing</h5>
    <p class="process-step-info"> In this step we will perform an analyzis</p>
  </div>
  <div class="process-steps" process-step="2">
    <h5 class="process-step-headline">2. Goal definition</h5>
    <p class="process-step-info"> In this step we will perform an analyzis</p>
  </div>
  <div class="process-steps" process-step="3">
    <h5 class="process-step-headline">3. Designing</h5>
    <p class="process-step-info"> In this step we will perform an analyzis</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section" id="section-three"></section>
```

Comment: You can do that with css only to be honest, you'll need javascript just for event listener, and updating a single custom property in your css.
I could make you a working version, but I don't think i'm allowed to, since you didn't not provide us with any codes that proves that you tried.

Comment: @AdnaneAr I have edited my question now and have added the code of my experimentation. I got stuck and think that my approach isn't the best. Maybe you can help with your solution.